# What are the performance ratios between multiplication accumulate operation, only addition, only multiplication and binary operations on CPU or GPU?

Tags: performance, intel, cpu-architecture, flops

I want to calculate theoretical speed up for my algorithm for some Neural Network and I want to know the performance ratios of Multiplication, Addition, FMA(Fused Multiplication Addition) and, Binary Operations.
I got to know that ratio (Multiplication accumulate operation) and a binary operation(64-bit) can be taken as 1.91 from [here](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ECCV_2018/papers/Diwen_Wan_TBN_Convolutional_Neural_ECCV_2018_paper.pdf).

I would like to know reasonable ratios for all these operations may be on general CPU, GPU!!
And this wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS) mentions that for Intel Core CPUs we have: 8 SP FLOPS/cycle with 4-wide SSE addition + 4-wide SSE multiplication.

So can I say if the addition operations and multiplication operations will take equal time(in isolation) and also Multiply Accumulate operation will take the same time as them?

Comment: On mainstream Intel (Skylake and later), and on Xeon Phi, FP mul/add/FMA all run on the same execution unit with the same throughput and latency, so the theoretical performance ratio is 1:1:1.  See https://agner.org/optimize/ and other performance links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.

Comment: Broadwell had 5 cycle FMA vs. 3 cycle mul or add latency, and FP add throughput was half of mul/FMA.